# Cannot start Appium on Device because of apk sign

Tags: appium-android, appium-java, apksigner

I’m encountering a problem in a terminal device that has Android 10 where my app is running. I tried to run appium and got the next error, it installed de Appium Settings apk successfully after signing it with the provided key and repeated the process for this one too but it failed. Do you guys know how to solve it?

I redo the process for every apk and got error on appium-uiautomator2-server-v5.7.8.apk